# How can I let Vim align like printf does?

Tags: vim, printf, alignment

I wanted to let Vim to sort variable declaration like the following:

```
NotifyNotification*    notification;
gboolean               success;
GError*                error = NULL;
```

Just like printf does, and I wanted to enable this when use `=` to align lines, make it the default align method, with `au FileType cpp`, is that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try Vim plugins [Align and AlignMaps](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=294). Check the [examples](http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/align.html#Examples) where you can find tables presenting what the plugins do. I think they do what you need.